# How to get innerXML attribute values using xml reader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a similar situation as the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayf5ffy5.aspx)

How to retrieve the "Price" and "Title" values of a book with given ISBN ?

Comment: why you guys vote to close?...I tried this since morning...

Comment: it is always a good idea to add more detail, and to include the code that one has already tried.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml =
        @"
        <bookstore>
          <book genre='novel' ISBN='10-861003-324'>
            <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
            <price>19.95</price>
          </book>
          <book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>
            <title>Pride And Prejudice</title>
            <price>24.95</price>
          </book>
        </bookstore>
        ";
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            var bookFound = false;
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "book")
                {
                    var isbn = xmlReader.GetAttribute("ISBN");
                    bookFound = isbn == "1-861001-57-5";
                }

                if (bookFound && xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "title")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("title: {0}", xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                }
                if (bookFound && xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "price")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("price: {0}", xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and if the XML file that you are reading is not very big and can fit into memory you could use an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to parse it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result =
    (from book in doc.Descendants("book")
     where book.Attribute("ISBN").Value == "1-861001-57-5"
     select new
     {
         Title = book.Element("title").Value,
         Price = book.Element("price").Value
     }).FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("title: {0}, price: {1}", result.Title, result.Price);
}
```

Comment: So, price and title is not attribute of book element ? Then how can I get the pricie and title of a particular element ?

Comment: @Relativity, what do you mean by `a particular element`? Like the price and title for a book with a given ISBN?

Comment: yes, how do we get price and title of a book with specific ISBN ?

Comment: @Relativity, I have updated my answer with an example of how to achieve that using a XmlReader. And next time when you ask a question please make sure that you provide more details about what you are asking and trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. so...Price and title are not attributes of book, right?

Comment: @Relativity, no, they are not attributes. They are child nodes. ISBN and genre are attributes of book.