# XmlReader: Read sub elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xmlreader

I've this kind of XML

```
...
<config>
  <parameters>
    <location attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing"/>
    <other attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing"/>
    <other2 attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing"/>
  </parameters>
</config
...
```

(Please note this is a very dummy example, I understood it make maybe no sense with concrete data).

I'm with my XmlReader currently on the `parameters` node, I would like to read all child element(until I saw the `</parameters>`)

How can I retrieve this with the XmlReader? (It's mandatory to use the XmlReader since I'm in bigger framework).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen this: [How to get innerXML attribute values using xml reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641738/how-to-get-innerxml-attribute-values-using-xml-reader)?

Comment: XmlReader.ReadSubTree would be my first port of call.

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah I could do that, but in my real case, I've something like 20+ possible childs type, so I prefer to read them, then see to what they correspond than trying to read a lot of things that are not here.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I will go check this method, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will write all subnotes of `<parameters>` to the StringBuilder named output, that should give you a hint on processing xml with the XmlReader:

## Code

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    bool seenParam = false;

    XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    ws.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
    {
        // Parse the file and write each of the nodes.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Did we've seen the a node named parameters?
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "parameters")
                seenParam = !seenParam;

            // If not, proceed with the next node
            if (!seenParam)
                continue;

            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                    writer.WriteAttributes(reader, false);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

```
<parameters>
  <location attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing">
    <other attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing">
      <other2 attribute1="toto" attribute2="anotherThing"></other2>
    </other>
  </location>
</parameters>
```